# WrongTypeOfReturnValue, when it's the expected type

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockito

I try to mock with mockito an object with this method:

```
public List<List<String>> readData(String range) throws IOException {
```

this is my mock definition:

```
    final List<List<String>> excel = jsonUtility.excelFromJson("bla.json");

    SpreadSheetHandlerImpl spreadSheetHandlerImpl = mock(SpreadSheetHandlerImpl.class);
    when(spreadSheetHandlerImpl.readData(anyString()))
     .thenReturn(ImmutableList.of(ImmutableList.of("a"),ImmutableList.of("b")))
            .thenReturn(excel);
```

why do i get this error?

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
ArrayList cannot be returned by toString()
toString() should return String
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.
```

as the signature returned type is `List<List<String>>`

Comment: try `doReturn(excel).when(spreadSheetHandlerImpl).readData(anyString())`  instead of when(..).thenReturn(...)

Comment: but I want to control two executions

Comment: `doReturn(ImmutableList.of(ImmutableList.of("a"),ImmutableList.of("b"))).doReturn(excel).when(spreadSheetHandlerImpl).readData(anyStr‌​ing())`  you can do the same like this

Comment: Is `readData` or `SpreadSheetHandlerImpl` marked `final`? Are you mocking anything else in the test? Can we see the rest of the test? (FWIW, if you have a SpreadSheetHandler interface, try mocking that: Mocking works best with interfaces, not concrete classes.)

Comment: any luck? or still same error?

Comment: I did:   `doReturn(ImmutableList.of(ImmutableList.of("a"),ImmutableList.of("b"),ImmutableList.of("a"))). //3 lines total
        doReturn(ImmutableList.of(ImmutableList.of("no need"),ImmutableList.of("need"),ImmutableList.of("no need"))). //3 lines total
        doReturn(excel).
                when(spreadSheetHandlerImpl).readData(anyString());`

don't know why the regular syntax didn't work. Do you?